# Resize partition using parted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, parted

I want to resize a partition on a 8002GB disk /dev/sdb1 using parted.

> Start 1000MB | End 4000MB | Size 3000MB | File system NTFS (and so on)

Current version of parted has replaced resize with resizepart.
I was able to use resizepart to change end to 100% i.e 8002GB but I can't seem to change the start from 1000MB to 1MB.

How can I change this partition to start from 1MB?

Comment: This is what Logical Volumes are meant for...! Back up, delete, create Logical Volume then start small and add as needed use LVM tool set

Answer (score 2):

`parted` doesn't have a command to change a partition's start offset. You can delete the partition with the `rm` command and recreate it with the correct offsets with the `mkpart` command. However, if you do that your filesystem will cease to function. Moving a partition requires re-writing filesystem structures; a function `parted` doesn't perform.

Instead, you can use `gparted` to move the partition, as described in their [documentation](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-move-partition).

Comment: I am on Ubuntu Server so no GUI. I guess gParted live USB it is then.